# Data generating model

Tags: bayesian

assuming I am to embark on an analysis of a given set of data on length of a movie, but already have a prior belief of 56 minutes on the average for a movie before seeing the data. How do I carry out a data generating model given that I now have my observed data on length of movies?

Answer (score 0):

### Prior Beliefs

For your data generating model you need to select a likelihood that you believe the data will be generated from. This could be any distribution as long as *you* believe it fits.

Let $M$ be a random variable that represents the movie length. Call your data generating model $\pi(m|\theta)$.

You now want to choose a prior distribution for $\theta$, there are many ways to do this, but a simple example could be, say you believe $\theta$ is going to be $\hat{\theta}$ but you are unsure on your beliefs and you think the actual value could deviate slightly from your beliefs by an equal amount each way. You might want to fit a normal distribution to this such that your data generated model has a mean of 56 minutes with your expected value for your prior, $\mathbb{E}(\theta)$.

Let $\pi(\theta)$ represent the probability of your prior model.

---

### Posterior Beliefs

Now you have observed some data, $m$, you can update your prior beliefs for $\theta$ using:

$$\pi(\theta|m) \propto \pi(m|\theta) \pi(\theta)$$

A really basic way to do this (which should only be used for discrete data) is *Exact Bayesian Computation*.

Here is a really simple step by step guide on how to do this:

1. Set $N =$ number of samples for $\theta$ you would like and let $i=0$
2. Make a single draw from the prior distribution for $\theta$, $\theta*$
3. Make a single draw from your data generating model $M|\theta*$, $m*$
4. If $m* = m$, add $\theta*$ to your sample and set $i = i+1$
5. If $i < N$ repeat from step 1.

You can now take an average of your samples for $\theta$ to find the average value.

---

### A few notes

1. If you are unsure on your prior beliefs you can use a *uninformative* prior which essentially means setting the variance of your prior model higher so that your final model is more reliant on the data rather than your beliefs.
2. There are many different sampling methods that can be used, above I described exact bayesian computation. A couple to look at are [MCMC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain_Monte_Carlo) and [ABC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_Bayesian_computation).
3. When estimating your final value for $\theta$ many different methods can be used, above I used the mean but you can use the mode or median or any you believe are right.
4. Bayesian is about *your* beliefs so you can experiment a little bit there does not have to be a wrong answer.

---

**Side note**: I am not an expert in Bayesian so I apologise if this does not help too much, I am currently doing a Bayesian module at University and so I am still learning new things about this everyday but I hope I have been able to help you or give you some better understanding.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I would point out that "56 minutes on the average for a movie" is not a good prior because it does not seem to be a distribution. A better prior would be "the average length of the movie is normally distributed with a mean of 56 and sigma of 25", or "the average length of a move has a Poisson distribution with mean 56", etc. Wikipedia has a [table of of tractable prior distributions.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#Table_of_conjugate_distributions)

Comment: @olooney this is true, thank you. I read it as fitting the video length such that the mean of the distribution is 56 minutes but yes fitting the mean to a distribution makes more sense.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your responses. it really helped.

Comment: @olooney, thank you too for the additional insight.